# Was the absence of R2's thrusters ever explained?

Tags: star-wars

Someone thought that in both AotC and RotS R2-D2 should have rockets built into his side legs, but if he still had the thrusters in ANH and beyond he never visibly used them- was there ever an explanation to why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### His thrusters were out of warranty by the time of the Original Trilogy.

> Industrial Automaton, Artoo's parent company, limited its factory warranty on astromech rockets to about 20 years.
>   -- Pablo Hidalgo, *The Official UK Star Wars Magazine*, issue 42 (Jan/Feb 2003)

Comment: My toaster is out of its warranty. That doesn't stop me using it

Comment: @Valorum Your toaster isn’t likely to malfunction in a way that would blow your legs off though.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - I'd be tempted to use it in an emegency, though. My quote on the dupe is far more useful since it identifies **that they stopped working a long time ago and that the lack of a warranty means that he can't get them fixed**

Comment: I must support @Valorum. Things out of warranty don't magically stop working; and in an emergency you'll use dangerous procedures regardless of warranties. R2D2 did some crazy shit anyway, it's not like it was a particularly careful droid...